# How do you make Paillets Feuilletine?

Tags: baking, crepe

Paillets Feuilletine, dried caramelised crepes. I have looked and cannot find any method for the making of this product. As it is in many of my books and recipes but not readily available in australia, im looking for some information on the making of it.

Comment: If they do lose some crispness you can bake them again to dry them out right before you use them, for maybe 5 mins at 150c. And in the case of vac packing, make sure you stop the machine before the cycle ends so as to leave some air inside of the bag, this way they wont compress and be completely destroyed. Alternatively you can find silica beads and put them inside of the container (in their own little bag, so as not to contaminate the feuilletine.) As well.

Answer (score 2):

After considerable searching, I found this tidbit buried in an an old Callebaut product catalog:  Pailleté feuilletine is broken up pieces of *crepes dentelles*.

[This video from Bryan Talbot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo3QeZrkG98) shows how to prepare crepes dentelles in considerable detail.  He indicates that he had to reverse engineer the recipe because none were available.  His ingredients are:

```
1/4 lb Butter 
1/2 Cup Sugar 
1/2 All Purpose Flour
1 Egg White
Pinch Of Salt
```

Mix the ingredients, spread *very* thinly on a parchment or silicone mat lined baking sheet, and bake at 400 F until golden brown, about 5 minutes.  If you are going to roll or mold them, do so when they are still very hot.

You could then crush it for pailleté feuilletine.  If you are going to do crush them, there probably is little point in rolling or molding them.

[Voici une autre vidéo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYoEOyyuWws), mais elle est en français.  It does not show the ingredients in the batter, but the outcome is very similar, which lends credence to the Talbot video.

Here is [another video from Jennifer Field](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfNMLtlHODw) showing her process of reverse engineering the crepres dentelles (one of her commentors points out this means "lacey crepes").  The video is long and shows the development process.  The final recipe and technique is somewhat different, as she paints the batter onto a hot griddle with a pastry brush, and gets a much more delicate product.  [Her blog entry](http://pastrychefonline.com/2010/11/23/pmat-live-episode-9-behind-the-curtain-crepes-dentelle-or-watch-jenni-make-many-mistakes-before-achieving-success/) has her recipe.

Update:  Another recipe, from [Brave Tart](http://bravetart.com/recipes/Feuilletine), where the author simply calls it feuilletine, rather than crepes dentelles.

Comment: love it, thanks. When it says "caramelized" crepe, do you think they are referring to caramel, or just really browned?

Comment: In this case, with a high sugar batter, those two things are overlapping.  Some of the browning will be due to the maillard reaction of the starches and proteins, but a lot will be true caramalization of the sugars in the dough.  So:  both.

Comment: What about storage? If i make a larger batch will it keep? Even vac packing, they will stale.

Comment: My best guess based on the recipes is that their biggest enemy would be humidity:  they would be very hydrophyilic and get soft or even soggy if not stored in an airtight container.  The second biggest factor would be rancidity of the butter.   They should keep quite well (weeks easily) if kept air tight.  They should probably freeze up to a year.    I would store them in small batches, in zip lock bags or jars, so that you are not opening them a lot.  Vacuum packing in a bag may crush them further, although that may not be undesirable.

Comment: Uh... what would be the unit for flour? (Admittedly, I’m too lazy to follow the links to find out.)