# What is on top of this and how do you make it?

Tags: baking, cake, chocolate, caramel, fondant

[image]

[Chocolate fondant picture on yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/la-folie-san-francisco?menu-item=the-sunset-warm-bittersweet-chocolate-fondant&select=_f47A5Q1EXXDb2l57y6PZw#pC1_eyeYmpUCv1itXilo7A). As you can see this is a picture of a chocolate fondant. However what is on top of it? I have seen this many times.

Comment: It's a brandy snap, they're often baked around a pole to create a hollow tube like: http://www.taste.com.au/recipes/19239/brandy+snaps however they can be baked flat for a disc presentation, or on the underside of a muffin tin to make a bowl etc. As for good recipes, I don't know, so I'm not writing an answer.

Comment: It's similar to a type of cookie I just made a few weeks ago called [Florentine Lace Cookies](http://www.americastestkitchen.com/recipes/7485-florentine-lace-cookies)

Comment: @setek Brandy snaps (effectively Paillets Feuilletine) are not baked around a pole, they are baked flat. When fully cooked and still hot, they remain pliable for about 30 seconds. You then roll them into tubes, or drape them over something like an upside down muffin tin to make a bowl

Comment: Recipe requests are off topic, so I removed that part of the answer. I also embedded the picture.

Comment: @TFD oops you're right, my mistake, I guess I mixed them up with cannoli.

Answer (score 3):

Most often they are called tuiles and they can be made in a number of ways, in some cases they are biscuit based or they can be made by melting sugar on a non-stick surface. and then cutting while the sugar is still warm and pliable.

If you wanted to make a classic biscuity tuile there is a recipe here:

http://www.finecooking.com/recipes/classic-tuile-cookies.aspx

For a sugar only variety you could consider using some fine sugar and a blow torch, in a similar way to a creme brûlée topping and using a metal cookie cutter to get the desired shape.

The benefit of the classic tuile recipe is that it can be adjusted in order to add flavourings e.g. vanilla or even spices.

Parmesan under a grill can also form a tuile as long as the grill isn't set to too high a temperature (chocolate and cheese go pretty nicely together...)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Paillets Feuilletine to me. There is a recipe here: [How do you make Paillets Feuilletine?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32692/how-do-you-make-paillets-feuilletine)